# change form with auto-page refresh

Tags: php, javascript, forms

It's a multiple form manipulation that for some reason, I can't figure out.

```
<? 
  if( $parameters['system'] == 1)
  { 
     $parameters['type'] = 1;    
  }
  elseif( $parameters['system'] == 6) 
  {
     $parameters['type'] = 2; 
  } 
?>
```

They enter the conditional clauses and on the screen the type parameter changes, however, the page requires a `"refresh"` in order for the change to ACTUALLY be applied.

**I tried creating some javascript functions to do this and calling it after the change to no avail. Any idea on how to handle this?**

Comment: currently, this is in a .tpl(Smarty) file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to reload your page with +1 for system.

```
<script>
   window.location = "thePage.php?system=<?=intval($parameters['system'])+1?>";
</script>
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work..I'm not sure why but it may have to do with the fact that it's on a .tpl file. :(

Comment: What do you need? Code to refresh the page?